# Server code execution

Tags: php, tcl

I have some TCL scripts on the server . I am using a client (html/php ) to call them . 
I want to know if each seperate http request ( to call a TCL script from php script ) executes in separate thread ? i.e can i have multiple instances calling the same TCL script ?
Could some one throw some light on this .

Regards,
Mithun

Comment: I have my PHP scripts and TCL scripts on the WAMP server. I am using function passthru() to execute the TCL script . So each call to the TCL scripts executes in different thread ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the web server plays a part in deciding if each http request executes a seperate thread. As far as apache, then yes, each request will execute in a seperate thread. As far as having mutiple instances of the tcl script - that all depends on how well the tcp script has been coded.

Answer (score 0):

If your php script is making a [system](https://www.php.net/system) or [exec](https://www.php.net/exec) call, it would be as though you made that same call in a standalone console.  The processes are effectively operating in different threads.